# Android can not fit requested classes in the main-dex file

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-multidex

Please help from going to mad

I build an android project it shows error `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I put below lines in Multi-dex-config.pro file.

```
keep class com.google.firebase.**{*;}
keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
keep class com.ustaadthehandyman.user.activities**{*;}</i>
```

After build again it shows error Cannot fit requested classes in the main-dex file (# methods: 67808 > 65536)

After edit `Multi-dex-config.pro` file like below

```
keep class com.google.firebase.provider**{*;}
keep class com.google.android.gms.provider** { *; }
keep class com.ustaadthehandyman.user.activities**{*;}</i>
```

It show another error `NoClassDefFoundError` in another class

I is any automated way to put required class in main dex file.

Please help me

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing Proguard/R8 (e.g. minification) with multidex. Better use the later, and disable Proguard minification (its harder to get it right).

See [Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) in the Android Documentation site.

Specifically, add the following if your `minSdkVersion` is 21+:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

If your app is below API 21 see the linked page for additional information.

Comment: Then remove minification `minifyEnabled false`. This should fix your issue.